# Using nested loops and indexing to create 2 1D arrays and a 2D array that changes row when the value changes, to then plot 3D graph

Tags: python, arrays, nested-loops

```
x = []
m1 = []
k1 = []
Cm = []
Ck = []
Cx = []
for m in arange(200,1300,200,dtype=int):
    for k  in arange(1E6,76E5,6E5,dtype=int):
        x1 = bisection(m,k,0.0001)
        x.append(x1)
        X = array(x)
        m1.append(m)
        m2 = array(m1)
        k1.append(k)
        k2 = array(k1)
        cm = 10*m - 2000
        Cm.append(cm)
        Cm1 = array(Cm)
        ck = (900 + 825*((k/1E6)**2)) - 1725*(k/1E6)
        Ck.append(ck)
        Ck1 = array(Ck)
        cx = 2400*((X**2)/4)
        Ct = (10*m - 2000) + (900 + 825*((k/1E6)**2)) - 1725*(k/1E6) +2400*((X**2)/4)

M,K = meshgrid(m2,k2)     
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,16))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(M,K,Ct, cmap=coolwarm)
plt.show
'''
```

thats the code so for but its producting 3 1D arrays, ideally I would like ct to be a 2d array that changes row when the value of m changes, so I can plot it against the mesh grid of M, K.
Any suggestions at all would be helpful

Comment: Code is not complete. All the import are missing. And What is the code or module of bissection  ? And plt.show miss the parenthesis : plt.show(). Please edit and include a working code so we can help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.